# Multiple sites on a single VPS — Nginx configuration

Tags: nginx, node.js

I'm trying to host 4 NodeJS processes on my VPS. Two on them are websites that must be accessible in a browser by their names, lets call them `a.com` and `b.com`. `a.com`runs on port 3000, and `b.com` runs on port 4000. Another one is a website that runs on port 7000 and doesn't have a domain name pointing to it, so I would like to access it using the IP address of the VPS and the port, like `0.1.2.3:7000`. The last one is a SocketIO process that runs on port 7500 and should also be accessible by it's address: `0.1.2.3:7500`, but I guess its configuration should be similar to the one running on 7000 so let's forget about it for now.

I think I'm supposed to use Nginx to do this, but I can't configure it to work. So far, I've managed to make `a.com` and `b.com` work correctly, but I can't access `0.1.2.3:7000`. What I did so far is create `a.com`, `b.com` and `c` (the one running on port 7000) configuration files in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` and created symlinks for them in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`.

### `a.com`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.a.com a.com
    access_log /var/log/nginx/a.com.access.log;
    rewrite_log on;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }
}
```

### b.com

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.b.com b.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/b.com.access.log;
    rewrite_log on;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000;
    }
}
```

### c

```
server {
    listen 7000;
    server_name  _;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/c.access.log;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7000;
    }
}
```

Like I said, I can already access `a.com` and `b.com` by typping their domain name in the address bar of a browser. How do I configure it to make `c` accessible through `0.1.2.3:7000`?

Comment: ` I can't access 0.1.2.3:7000` --> can you elaborate this statement? any error message you get?

Comment: I changed the port nginx listens to from 7000 to 6000 like drookie suggested. Now I don't see any error page, just no response at all when I try to `GET 0.1.2.3:6000`.

Comment: Please **do not** update the question to include the changes proposed in an answer.

Comment: Thank you, @AD7six .  He's quite right - editing your question after the fact to include someone else's answer is just going to confuse things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your C configuration contains a conflicting bind to the 7000 port. This is the reason you cannot make it work. I suppose something is already bound to the 7000 port, since you are proxying requests there.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. Now nginx listens to port `6000` and proxies to `7000`. But it's still not working. I don't get the error page anymore, but I don't get any response either.

Comment: Check the nginx logs, see how the backend reacts and what does it give as a status. Check the backend logs.

Comment: Add to the log_formant nginx is using the `$upstream_addr $upstream_status` fields and see what nginx thinks about the statuses backend is answering with. Post 'em here.

Comment: I don't what causes it, but it's working now. I reloaded the nginx configuration a second time and that caused it to work I guess. Thanks for your help.